# How to make a Bode plot of an inverting amplifier?

Tags: bode-plot, inverting-amplifier

I am trying to create a Bode plot of the open-loop gain and the closed-loop gain of an inverting amplifier using Mathematica.

I know the documentation of the bode plot in Mathematica (BodePlot[lsys]) but I do not know what to put in the brackets to plot the function.

For reference to the problem I am doing, here is the setup:

[image: Image of Inverted Op Amp]

R<sub>F</sub> = 100 kΩ
R = 10 kΩ

I calculated the low-frequency gain to be -10, and the bandwidth fb to be: 90.9 kHz.

Comment: how did you calculate the bandwidth? that is an ideal OPAMP with resistive-only components so theoretically the BW will be infinity.

Comment: `BodePlot[...]` takes a system model as the first argument. For convenience, s-domain transfer function expressions can be input directly, like `BodePlot[1/(1+s)]`. The open-loop response is of the first order, the closed-loop response is of the second order. So figure the time constants, look up 1st and 2nd order system s-domain ("Laplace") response formulas in terms of time constants, and give those to `BodePlot`.

Answer (score 1):

If the op amp is unity-gain-stable, you can model it for first-approximation type calculations of small-signal as just an integrator. (i.e. the very-low-frequency behavior will rarely matter). The OP amp open loop gain would be

A_OL = ω_A / jω = (-j ω_A) / ω

where ω_A = (2π)(f_GBW)

Then proceed with the feedback network based on that. There is more to it in reality, but this will go a long way.